# rabbitmq in ruby on mac not received message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitmq. I tried to follow a tutorial on mac using ruby and rabbitmq. I created two .rb files.

worker.rb

```
require 'bunny'
connection=Bunny.new
connection.start
channel= connection.create_channel
queue=channel.queue('hello')

begin
  puts ' Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
  queue.subscribe(block: true) do |delivery_info, _properties, body|
  puts " [x] Received #{body}"
  # imitate some work
  sleep body.count('.').to_i
  puts ' [x] Done'
end
rescue Interrupt => _
  conn.close

  exit(0)
end
```

and receive.rb

```
 require 'bunny'
    connection=Bunny.new
    connection.start
    channel= connection.create_channel
    queue=channel.queue('hello')
    begin
      puts ' Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
      queue.subscribe(block: true) do |_delivery_info, _properties, body|
        puts "  Received #{body}"
    end
rescue Interrupt => _
  conn.close

  exit(0)
end
```

the rabbitmq server is open. When I run ruby new_task.rb, I see the output [x] Sent Hello World!, which is as expected. When I run ruby worker.rb. It show waiting for message... but never receive the message. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend carefully studying the [tutorial code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/ruby) and compare it with what you have written.

Since you did not provide your code for `new_task.rb`, I assume you are using the code as it appears [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/blob/master/ruby/new_task.rb). That code expects a queue named `task_queue`, yet the code you provide above uses a queue named `hello`.